# Solr Colored Highlighting isn't working for me

Tags: solr

I'm out of ideas for getting the colored highlighter working in Solr. I would like to get it so that different words in the search are highlighted with different colors. Which is what I understand the

I'm using this query (and have tried many variations of it):

```
{Solr ip address}:{port}/solr/{core}/select?hl=on&hl.useFastVectorHighlighter=true&hl.fragmenter=regex&hl.highlightMultiTerm=true&hl.method=fastVector&indent=on&q=Car%20jacking&hl.fragListBuilder=simple&hl.fragmentsBuilder=colored&hl.q=red%20truck&hl.fl=cad_incident_remarks&wt=json
```

And in the managed-schema I have set ChargeDescription as follows:

```
<field name="ChargeDescription" type="text_general" multiValued="false" indexed="true" required="false" stored="true" termVectors="true" termPositions="true" termOffsets="true"/>
```

I believe using default solrconfig.xml.

FYI, I understand that the colored fragmentBuilders requires fastVector, which requires termVectors="true" termPositions="true" termOffsets="true" in the schema.

The highlighting results I get are:

```
"highlighting":{
    "baltimore-22252":{},
    "baltimore-127544":{},
    "baltimore-55956":{},
    "baltimore-55957":{},
    "baltimore-26358":{},
    "baltimore-65455":{},
    "baltimore-130672":{}}}
```

Any thoughts or suggestions?  Ideally an example that shows the colored highlighter working.

Thanks!

Comment: Is highlighting working at all? I can't see any highlighted segments returned? Also, if you're going to change the managed schema, you'll have to do it through the API (or shut down all servers and manually update the xml-file before starting them up again, at least).

Comment: So highlighting does work if I do something like this:
http://{Ip address}:{port}/solr/{core}/select?indent=on&q=Theft%20Value&wt=json&hl=true&hl.fl=ChargeDescription,IncidentOffense&hl.fragmentsBuilder=colored

Returns results using <em></em> tags.

I have restarted the server every time I've made such a change.  Thanks!